# Why isn't my filter working against my Python list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, filter

I'm using Python 3.7.  I want to apply a regex to every element in my list. Here's the list

```
>>> title_words 
['that', 'the', 'famous', 'ukulele', 'medley', '"somewhere', 'over', 'the', 'rainbow/what', 'a', 'wonderful', 'world"', 'by', 'israel', 'kamakawiwoê»ole', 'was', 'originally', 'recorded', 'in', 'a', 'completely', 'unplanned', 'session', 'at', '3:00', 'in', 'the', 'morning,', 'and', 'done', 'in', 'just', 'one', 'take.']
```

I thought running a filter against the list would do the trick, but note that when I run

```
>>> list(filter(lambda s: re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s), title_words))
['that', 'the', 'famous', 'ukulele', 'medley', '"somewhere', 'over', 'the', 'rainbow/what', 'a', 'wonderful', 'world"', 'by', 'israel', 'kamakawiwoê»ole', 'was', 'originally', 'recorded', 'in', 'a', 'completely', 'unplanned', 'session', 'at', '3:00', 'in', 'the', 'morning,', 'and', 'done', 'in', 'just', 'one', 'take.']
```

The element '"somewhere' remains with its quote at the beginning.  I ran the regex in isolation and it seems to work fine but things break down when I apply the filter.  Where are things going wrong?

Comment: did you read the signature of `filter` function?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a list in python, not an array. Not that it matters for the answer, but it can make a big difference when trying to search for solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` checks if the result of the filter function is "truthy" to include it in the result or not. It doesn't change the values of the elements. Here you're calling `re.sub` that returns a non-empty string each time.

So your original list is unchanged. You mean a simple list comprehension:

```
filtered = [re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s) for s in title_words]
```

also, even when filtering is needed, `filter` isn't that useful with `lambda`, it just overcomplicates things when a list/generator comprehension with a condition can do the same thing and it's clearer. Now I realize that you probably wanted `map` instead (with also `list()` to force iteration and get a hard list), which would have worked, but still overly complicated:

```
list(map(lambda s: re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s), title_words))
```

(the only interest in this approach is when you use `multiprocessing.map` module to parallelize tasks, but here it doesn't apply)

Answer (score 1):

You're using filter when what you actually want is map. Replace filter with map and you should get the result you're looking for.

```
list(map(lambda s: re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s), title_words))
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by Jean and Olivier, list comprehensions are preferable if you're just going to convert the map into a list anyway. Using map would only be appropriate if you had a very long list of title_words and you did not want to apply the transformation to the entire list, but instead wanted to iterate through each item (i.e. if you're logic may potentially stop at a specific title_word and not need to look at all title_words that come after).

```
fixed_title_words = map(lambda s: re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s), title_words)

for title in fixed_title_words:
    if title == 'medley':
        # Perform some action
        break
```